# Fatal Error 0x80070000e in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, crash, hresult

I'm getting a message box pop up with the following message half way through a debugging session. This is happening intermittently but every time it blows, I have to restart VS2012 and IIS express which is pretty annoying and is losing 10 minutes every time it goes bang.

*A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs ot be terminated. For more details, please see the Microsoft Help and Support web site. HRESULT=0x80070000e. ErrorCode=0x0.*

This points to out of memory but I've got 24GiB of RAM in this box and am running Windows 7 x64 Pro. ProcMon is reporting 37% RAM used. I've got a 320GiB SAS disk with 110GiB free as well so it's not disk space!

Does anyone know what this is?

There is a connect case open but as usual, it's damn useless as nothing has been done.

Comment: 24 GB of RAM doesn't do you any good for 32-bit processes.  Keep an eye on the commit size for devenv.exe in Task Manager as well as the kernel memory pool usage.  Disable add-ins.

Comment: Thanks - I have no add-ins loaded. VS is hitting over 3Gb RAM which might be the problem. VS is a useless piece of junk.

Comment: @pointyhat Have you managed to overcome this? What have you done? I'm experiencing this in VS2012 Update 4.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an extension conflict, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21563003/1037948) indicating that an expired trial of Redgate Reflector was throwing a `NullReferenceError`?

Have you considered that it could be recursive code resulting in a stack overflow?  Similar to what [this answer reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765640/1037948) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076791/1037948).  The real question is, of course, how do you identify the recursion without stepping through everything...

Answer (score 0):

I found toggling the "Set as Startup Project" option found by right clicking a project in the Solution Explorer, to another project, starting a debugging session and then you can switch back to the original start up project and every thing works again.

I had this happen to be debugging a test, so in that context, the start up project is not even important but that did not matter, I was getting this error message all the same.