# Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 Debugger Crashing

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Update 1 for Visual Studio 2013. Every time my program throws an exception, the Visual Studio debugger crashes - whether or not the exception is handled.

Visual Studio also crashes whenever it hits a breakpoint.

The Windows Error Reporting dialog pops up and gives the options to debug or restart Visual Studio. If I click debug and and open with VS, it also crashes - debugging itself! This is leading me to believe that there is not a problem with my app, but rather with Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Professional 2013 (12.0.30110.00 Update 1)
Windows Server 2012 R2 x64

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, maybe post the relevant parts of the code so someone might try to reproduce the problem? Debugging works for me so far without any problems...

Comment: @walther What parts would be relevant? My app is about 105k lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, it turns out, was that I had installed a trial version of Redgate Tools' .NET Reflector. The trial's expiration had coincided with my installation of Update 1. .NET Reflector was throwing a `NullReferenceException` and hence crashing Visual Studio.

The solution was simple: disable or uninstall the .NET Reflector extension.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is: get more data about the crash and see whether it's caused by Visual Studio itself or any plugins which might not be compatible any more.

Set up the registry for [Windows Error Reporting to store local dump files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), reproduce the crash and analyze the dump in [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx) (because Visual Studio is not working well).

Some steps in WinDbg:

- open crash dump
- `.symfix c:\mysymbols`
- `.reload`
- `.exr -1`
- `.loadby sos clr` (if it's a .NET exception)
- `!pe` (if it's a .NET exception)
- `!clrstack` (if it's a .NET exception)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already solved the problem. +1 for a great answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I also get Problems with IDE crashing after installed "update 1". My Workaround: uninstall that update. It is really Buggy and NOT production ready. Maybe it is caused by a Extension, but I dont have time to debug Tools I have to use to get my work done, I Need working Tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck in this problem for 3 days until I discovered that the problem was in try-catch blocks. Viewing this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, I realized the importance of not leaving a "catch" empty.

Well, this problem happened to me while developing a simple sequential workflow SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2013 in "OnTaskChanged" methods.

I hope the answer may help someone else.